# Using beautifulsoup, how to I reference table rows in html page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html page that looks like:

```
    <html>

    ..

    <form post="/products.hmlt" ..>
    ..

    <table ...>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>
       <td>part info</td>
    ..
    </tr>

    </table>

    ..


</form>

..

</html>
```

I tried:

```
form = soup.findAll('form')

table = form.findAll('table')  # table inside form
```

But I get an error saying:

ResultSet object has no attribute 'findAll'

**I guess the call to findAll doesn't return a 'beautifulsoup' object? what can I do then?**

**Update**

There are many tables on this page, but only 1 table INSIDE the  tag shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`findAll` returns a list, so extract the element first:

```
form = soup.findAll('form')[0]
table = form.findAll('table')[0]  # table inside form
```

Of course, you should do some error checking (i.e. make sure it's not empty) before indexing into the list.

Answer (score 2):

I like ars's answer, and certainly agree w/ the need for error-checking;
especially if this is going to be used in any kind of production code.

Here's perhaps a more verbose / explicit way of finding the data you seek:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
html = '''<html><body><table><tr><td>some text</td></tr></table>
    <form><table><tr><td>some text we care about</td></tr>
    <tr><td>more text we care about</td></tr>
    </table></form></html></body>'''    
soup = bs(html)

for tr in soup.form.findAll('tr'):
    print tr.text
# output:
# some text we care about
# more text we care about
```

For reference here is the cleaned-up HTML:

```
>>> print soup.prettify()
<html>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     some text
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <form>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>
      some text we care about
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      more text we care about
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```